# Cannot assign my DefaultListModel to my JList in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a jList that was generated by NetBeans. I have declared a DefaultListModel but cannot link to up to the jList. My code is below and I have also tried using .setMethod.

```
        DefaultListModel modeljLstShoppingCartName;
        modeljLstShoppingCartName = new DefaultListModel();
        jLstShoppingCartName = new JList(modeljLstShoppingCartName);
        modeljLstShoppingCartName.addElement("Testing1");
```

The error I am receiving here is on the entire third line where it is saying:

```
incompatible types
  required: java.awt.List
  found:    javax.swing.JList
```

I have imported:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
```

Any help would be great as I've spent a few hours at this but with no success.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding:

```
incompatible types
  required: java.awt.List
  found:    javax.swing.JList
```

This could be little more than a careless mistake. I'm betting that you have declared your jLstShoppingCartName variable as a java.awt.List variable not a javax.swing.JList variable.